# How to properly call a protected API route with a token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postman, express-jwt

I have this route in my API app:

```
router.get('/users', auth, function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.json(users);
  });
});
```

In postman I do the api call like this:

> URL + users?token=*token*

But this returns:

> ## Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]

How can I properly do the api call with a token in postman?

Comment: Trying to send this in headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got indicates the right format you need to use for the header:

> Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]

You can try this in Postman

[image: Postman config]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the header to the http

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
});
```

after doing this your requests will be sent with this header
take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: in postman you can add headers so add a header, with name 'Authorization' and then add the value 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w' no colens

Comment: and where do I add the token then? I have generated a token with my login call but where do I paste it in postman

Comment: so when you click the headers button in the key field you type 'Authorization' in the value field you type 'Basic yourToken'

Comment: it was Bearer *token* I needed to type

Answer (score 0):

You can create a http interceptor service like this

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
        // Add authorization token to headers
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
            }
            return config;
        },

        // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
        responseError: function(response) {

            if (response.status === 401) {
                $location.path('/login');
                // remove any stale tokens
                $cookieStore.remove('token');
                return $q.reject(response);
            } else {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }
    };
})
```

And then add the service into the interceptors like this

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
})
```